# How can I see a list of all users on the logon screen?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I'm trying to "configure" my Windows 7 Professional logon screen to facilitate multiple users for a shared-computer environment.

Could someone please share how to make it NOT only display the last user to use the computer to facilitate multiple users?

Comment: Is the computer attached to a domain?

Comment: The computer is configured for a domain but it is rarely connected to that domain.  (Most access is for local users.)

Comment: Are you aiming to get the Welcome screen with a list of click-able avatars for local users, or to just not have the last name displayed (for security reasons)?

Comment: You'll want to make this question way more clear and declarative.  You'll want to say "I want the computer to do this." Because otherwise the answer to your question is simply, "Don't turn on the computer. Voila!!! Not displayed!!"

Comment: I think he want the list of clickable user icon you get in a non-domain environment while still being in the domain. Right away I would say that is not possible. I am not sure why we have an accepted answer though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I have correctly understood what you are trying to achieve, you should follow these steps:

1. Open up your "Local Group Policy Editor" by running "gpedit.msc"
2. Navigate to "Security Options"

   [image]
3. Under the Security Options under the Local Policies, scroll down till you find the "Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name" and then enable that policy.

   [image]

Hope this is what your trying to achieve and hope it helps.  Please let me know if your looking for something different.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1).  _[By the way, I edited it so that the images appear as part of the answer instead of being links to an external site.  You may find the "upload" option of interest (that's the feature I used) which is accessed by clicking on the icon in the editor's toolbar that resembles a 1970s-style polaroid photograph.]_

Comment: Oh great, didn't really notice that.  Thanks for the nice update.

Comment: This in fact removes the last user's name, but it won't present the non-domain login screen which lists all the local users. I note this (and asked for clarification) because the OP said "how to make it NOT only display the last user". It's the "not only" that makes me think they want the click-able list (and they're not actually worried about displaying who was logged in last).