# Enabling welcome screen Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, login-screen, windows-embedded-7, security-policy

I want the list of available users (without the hidden admin account etc) displayed.  To facilitate an easier login experience.

Things I have tried:

- Security policy editor:
  secpol | Local Policies | Security Options | Interactive Logon: do not display last user name -> Disabled (and enabled just for kicks)
- Group Policy editor: gpedit | Administrative Tools | System | Logon | Always use classic logon -> Disabled (and enabled just for kicks)

Sources for my trouble shooting so far:

- [How can I see a list of all users on the logon screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/354856/how-can-i-see-a-list-of-all-users-on-the-logon-screen)
- http://www.thewindowsclub.com/make-windows-7-8-use-classic-logon-screen

Comment: This device on a domain?

Comment: I've got no clue. If ( http://i.imgur.com/dKqYHIu.png ) is what you're referring to, this was enabled by default for me. What template did you use when building your Windows Embedded 7 installation, or was it a custom template? What edition are you using?